# How $GF(p^n) = K_{\langle \sigma_p^n \rangle}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-explanation

The following is a part of Example 53.8 from A First Course in Abstract Algebra - Fraleigh :

[image]

Where $GF(p^{12})$ means the unique Galois field of order $p^{12}$ and $K_{\langle \sigma_p^n \rangle}$ is the largest subfield of K fixed by all elements of the cyclic group $\langle \sigma_p^n \rangle$ and $\langle \sigma_p(a) \rangle=a^p$ for all $a \in K$.     No matter how much I think about it I can't figure out why $GF(p^n) = K_{\langle \sigma_p^n \rangle}$ in the diagram. I can't even understand how $p^n = |K_{\langle \sigma_p^n \rangle}|$. please help, thanks!

Comment: $\sigma_p^{12}=\iota$ so clearly it fixes all of $K$. In general the set of things fixed by $\sigma_p^n$ is the set of roots of $X^{p^n}-X$, and this equation has not got any repeated roots, so there are $p^n$ roots. [These are just hints.]

Comment: @ancientmathematician could you guide me through the claims you made : 1. "the set of things fixed by σ_p^n is the set of roots of X^{p^n}−X", 2. "this equation has not got any repeated roots" (I don't know if I use concept of derivative for repeated root for finite fields)?

Comment: Even in characteristic $p$ it's clear that if $f(X)=(X-a)^2 g(X)$ then $X-a$ divides $f'(X)$. In the case of $X^{p^k}-X$ in char $p$ the derivative is $(-1)$ so there can be no repeated roots.

Comment: If $\sigma$ is the Frobenius map $x\mapsto x^p$ then $\sigma^{k}(x)=x^{p^k}$; so $x$ is fixed if it is a root of $X^{p^k}-X$.

Comment: Other facts you need are that the set of roots of $X^{p^k}-X$ is closed under addition/subtraction and multiplication/division-not-by-0.